# How to copy an 800GB mongoDB in a few hours?

Tags: mongodb

I will visit a client's industry location for a few hours and have to copy the data from his mongoDB server. The data is currently above 800gb in size. I tried to replicate the data remotely but it is very slow, and hence I will visit the physical location to clone the data. Few options I found are LVM, mongodump, mongoexport, and until now LVM seems the best option. Is there a js query that can solve this situation or what might be the best course of action for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Take the disk snapshot and point your mongo to the same data folder. This we follow to dump prod data to qa

Comment: This is the wrong site. You should ask to https://serverfault.com/, it is a question of system administration, not for programmers.

Comment: Thanks karthik. Do I take the snapshot remotely or when I am physically at the client's location? And if the snapshot is created in the same data folder, how do I copy it over to my external HDD ?Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Giacomo, I will post it there.